# JSON schema validation failed: resource: String does not match pattern:^/[^/~!#\$%^|\s`@&*()\-+={}\[\]:;"'<>,?/\|\\]+(/[^/~!#\

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, apex

I'm trying to embed Jasper Reports into APEX App. I'm able to gather reports from samples (samples on JasperCommunity website), however, when I'm trying to get created by me and colleagues reports - every time I have the same error:

> JSON schema validation failed: resource: String does not match pattern: ^/[^/~!#\$%^|\s`@&*()\-+={}\[\]:;"'<>,?/\|\\]+(/[^/~!#\$%^|\s`@&*()-+={}[]:;"'<>,?/\|\]+)*$.

In other words I can't get any of our reports apart from the samples (e.g. /public/Samples/Reports/03._Store_Segment_Performance_Report"). I think the case is that the path to the Report is wrong, but I've tried all possible and impossible options and none of them works. Anyone any ideas please ?! Thanks

P.S. APEX 4.2.6, JasperServer 6.0. And finally, I can get samples Reports ONLY under the JasperAdmin user, simple User always got an error - 'Access Denied'. Why ?!?!?!

Comment: You need to understand the concept of expressions. Think out-of-box, whats wrong with this json?
In fact, all these questions , properly considered , raise doubts about whether the monitoring of consumer preferences requires the precision and the definition of corporate paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. 
If anyone interested - when specify the actual path, in Jasper: right click on Report(or Dashboard, AdHocView etc.) and copy the path from it. As it differs from when you point mouse on it (e.g. adding the underscores etc.), and paste this actual path into your javascript code into HTML section in your web app. Thanks